# Include independent list of references, sorted differently from the main ref list, at an arbitrary location of the document

Tags: biblatex, memoir, sorting

I have a pretty strict requirement for a document (I'm currently using `memoir`), which must:

1. use `biber`/`biblatex` in the usual way based on a primary bib file (e.g., `main.bib`), and sort the resulting list of refs by author then year.
2. at some other point in the text, I want to print out a list of all the refs of type `article` from a secondary bib file (e.g., `extra.bib`), sorted by youngest to oldest.

Is there some `biblatex` voodoo that would make this easy-ish?